# Connecting RedShift on AWS through Socks proxy from remote Hadoop/UNIX server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, sqoop

I need to establish a JDBC connection from my Hadoop Linux environment to the Redshift database. I've tried by setting the env variables in the shell and initiate sqoop by setting the below environment variables, it didn't work.

```
$export socks_proxy=hostName
$export http_proxy=hostName
$export http_proxyPort=1080 
$export https_proxy=hostName
$export https_proxyPortName=1080
$export socksProxyHost=hostName
```

Tried setting up from the spark shell and running the JDBC connection from the shell that didn't work either here is my spark shell and JDBC connection string 
    spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dsocks.ProxyHost=HostName 
    --jars RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.7.1003.jar,spark-redshift_2.10-1.0.0.jar,spark-
    redshift_2.10-2.0.0.jar

```
val df = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> 
"jdbc:redshift://RedShiftHostName:Port/databaseName?ssl=true&sslfactory=com.amazon.redshift.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&user=UNAME&password=PASSWORD", "dbtable" -> "(select * from information_schema.tables) tmp", "driver" -> "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver"));`
```

Here is the common error I'm getting from sqoop and spark

[image: Spark/sqoop Common Error]

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong from spark/sqoop ? Can I know if there is any other way to run the JDBC from the shell script without leveraging the Hadoop echo systems? May be with some java code through the shell ?

Thanks in advance, appreciate all your answers with examples.

Comment: Hi - I'm trying to do the same.  Did you ever work this out?

Comment: I got to know that it is not possible with RedShift because redshift driver will not support proxy configurations.